# Find inverse $z$-transform of $\dfrac{(z-1)^2}{z^3}$

Tags: inverse, transformation, z-transform

How can I find inverse z transform of $$X(z)=\frac{(z-1)^{2}}{z^{3}}$$

What I did:

I am thinking to do  Partial Fraction Decomposition or long division. Is there another method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$X(z) = \frac{(z-1)^2}{z^3} = \frac{z^2-2z+1}{z^3} = z^{-1} - 2z^{-2} + z^{-3}. $$
It follows that 
$$x[n] = \begin{cases}
1,& n=1\\
-2,& n=2\\
1,& n=3\\
0,& \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$